# ejabberd XMPP message archive management: no message received

Tags: android, xmpp, ejabberd, asmack

I am trying to implement message archive feature in an Android XMPP client, but it is not sending back any messages to client. Server configuration is correct.
XMPP Server used : ejabberd 15.11

IQ sent for getting archived messages from muc

```
<iq type='set' id='21564' to='bb124cc06ec6b8a5@conference.my.ip'>
<query xmlns='urn:xmpp:mam:0'>
    <x xmlns='jabber:x:data' type='submit'>
        <field var='FORM_TYPE' type='hidden'>
            <value>urn:xmpp:mam:0</value>
        </field>
        <field var='with'>
            <value>bb124cc06ec6b8a5@conference.my.ip</value>
        </field>
    </x>
    <set xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm'>
        <max>20</max>
    </set>
</query>
```

Responses received from server

1st response :

```
<message to='f748181bd1385940@my.ip/Smack' from='bb124cc06ec6b8a5@conference.my.ip'>
    <fin xmlns='urn:xmpp:mam:0'>
    </fin>
</message>
```

2nd response :

```
<message to='f748181bd1385940@my.ip/Smack' from='bb124cc06ec6b8a5@conference.my.ip'>
    <fin xmlns='urn:xmpp:mam:0'>
    </fin>
    <delay xmlns=urn:xmpp:delay stamp=2015-12-10T08:23:43.05600:00 from=my.ip>Resent, Offline Storage
    </delay>
</message>
```

Need help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you enable archiving for your session ?

Comment: we have done only this kind settings in ejabberd config file

`mod_mam:
    default: always
  mod_muc:
    ## host: "conference.@HOST@"
    access: muc
    access_create: muc_create
    access_persistent: muc_create
    access_admin: muc_admin
    history_size: 10
    default_room_options:
      mam: true
      persistent: true
      public: true`

do i need any thing else to do after successful authentication in client ?

Answer (score 0):

You can send msgs again.Try these msgs.